# How Do I Sort By An Inner Array Using IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I have an NSArray and within the array each item has an inner array called "venue" and then within that another array called "location". I would like to sort the array by the "distance" value within each "location" array.

Can someone point me in the right direction, this is the array.

```
{
    venue =         {
        beenHere =             {
            count = 0;
            marked = 0;
        };
        location =             {
            address = "845 Market St.";
            city = "San Francisco";
            country = "United States";
            crossStreet = "Westfield Food Emporium";
            distance = 137;
            lat = "37.78459765160777";
            lng = "-122.40650538423186";
            postalCode = 94103;
            state = CA;
        };
    };
},{
    venue =         {
        beenHere =             {
            count = 0;
            marked = 0;
        };
        location =             {
            address = "845 Market St.";
            city = "San Francisco";
            country = "United States";
            crossStreet = "Westfield Food Emporium";
            distance = 137;
            lat = "37.78459765160777";
            lng = "-122.40650538423186";
            postalCode = 94103;
            state = CA;
        };
    };
},
```

At the minute I am using the following but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending: YES];

                self.venueObject = [venueObject sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

Thanks

Oliver

Comment: Are you sure that `venue` is an Array? It seems a dictionary.

Comment: I don't see venue or location are arrays, but objects ... please simplify your example code to contain only the significant parts.

Comment: I have simplified the example above, basically I want to extract the results from foursquare into an array but have them ordered by the distance value.

Comment: @IconicDigital: Note that “array” in Cocoa (and Cocoa Touch, which is what you're using) does not mean the same thing as in PHP and Perl. An array is strictly a linear collection of objects, retrievable by sequential index. You're referring to an associative array, which Cocoa calls a dictionary. The data you showed above doesn't contain any arrays, only dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an array of dictionaries, and want to sort buy some value within those dictionaries sub-keys.

You need to use the `sortedArrayUsingComparator`: method.

Something like this should work for you:

```
NSArray * sortedVenues = [venues sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * venue1, NSDictionary * venue2) {
    float distance1 = [[venue1 valueForKeyPath: @"location.distance"] floatValue];
    float distance2 = [[venue2 valueForKeyPath: @"location.distance"] floatValue];

    if (distance1 > distance2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (distance1 < distance2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```